# Why squares don't fit inside div

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling to fill div element with square cells entirely.
right now these square cells fall out of the div, don't fit properly etc.
I am not sure what causes it.
Any ideas?

```js
var cell_side_len = 50;

var grid_width = 400;
var grid_height = 300;

var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.style.border = "solid black";
container.style.width = grid_width+"px";
container.style.height = grid_height+"px";

for(var i = 0; i < grid_width/cell_side_len; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < grid_height/cell_side_len; j++){
    var cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.style.height = cell_side_len + 'px';
    cell.style.width = cell_side_len + 'px';
    cell.style.border = "1px solid black";
    cell.style.float = "left";
    container.appendChild(cell);
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Box model basics, bet you are not accounting for the border. Why don't you just use modern CSS with grid or flexbox?

Comment: Or perhaps a [box sizing reset](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the content width of each cell to be 50px, and then adding a 1px border on each side, making each cell have a total width of 52px. This does not fit evenly into the 400px-width container.

You can fix this by saying "when I say width, I mean the content, the padding, and the border all together!". To do so, you should add the following CSS:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

To do that in JavaScript, you would write

```
cell.style["box-sizing"] = "border-box";
// or
cell.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
```

Comment: More about box-sizing and a useful starting point for one's CSS: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Can whoever just downvoted every answer here please tell me what issue they take with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Problem you have is the fact the border is NOT part of the width/height. So what you have have is everything is a width of 52px, not 50px. This is the basic box model.

What can you do?

- Change your width to 48
- or Use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
- or Drop the border for outline
- or use a modern approach with flexbox or grid.

Comment: would you pls elaborate how would I use modern approach to build background grid for container div...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox